# Next.js with Sass occurs on error saying " You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type error"

Tags: javascript, css, sass, next.js

I tried to several times to wire up my next.js and scss but it does not work.

I thought I set up everything to compile my file with scss.

The error saying that

```
/scss/style.scss 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> .example {
|   color: blue;
| }
```

here is the code :

**next.config.js**

```
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
module.exports = withSass();
```

**_document.js**

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

export default class extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <Head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/style.css" />
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <div id="modal" />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import "../scss/style.scss";

import axios from "axios";

const Index = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="example">hello</div>
      <header>
        <Header />
      </header>
      <section>
        <Body stores={props.data} />
      </section>
      <footer>
        <Footer />
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**style.scss** in SCSS folder

```
.example {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add `import "../scss/style.scss";` to your `_document.js`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But It was not the reason of this error. next.config.js file is supposed to be inside of project directory (next to pages folder and package.json file). I placed the file in wrong place in the first time